# как результат работы цикла for Python записать в одну переменную?

Tags: python

Собственное вопрос, как результат работы цикла, все данные которые он выводит через print записать в одну переменную? Ответ дан, как это сделать через список. А как это сделать через строку?

Comment: преобразовть список в строку?

Answer (score 1):

1. Перед циклом создать пустую строку. `s = ""`
2. В каждой итерации присоединять к строке результат работы цикла.
3. После цикла в `s` будут результаты работы одной строкой.

Answer (score 0):

```
#Создаём пустую переменную    
log=''
for i in range(10):
    print(i)
    #Записываем результат
    log+=str(i)+'\n'

#Выводим результат
print('log:\n '+log)
```